# Linux Debian 9 daemon stdin (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, service, debian, daemon

Is there a way to pipe a value into a daemon so that when the daemon starts it populates the service options required to start successfully. I'm running Debian 9 and here is a snippet of code:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --chuid $USER \
$START_STOP_OPTIONS --exec $DAEMON  -- \
--username $VPN_USER --password $VPN_PASSWORD --domain $VPN_DOMAIN \
$OPTIONS $VPN_SERVER:$VPN_SERVER_PORT&
```

Ideally I need to parse `Y` into the daemon otherwise the service being executed by the daemon cannot start correctly. I've tried a mixture of stdin from `echo` `>>>` `<<<` inside and outside of `--exec` but no luck...

**TLDR;**
How do I get this to work?
`echo "Y" | start-stop-daemon ...`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to have a `-y` switch(for example) in the program arguments that will start the daemon without prompts. In general it's a very bad practice to not have this option.

Otherwise I just tested with a simple python script that prompts for "Y" and it works.
Script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from time import sleep
k = input("prompt:")

if k == "Y":
    print("exit!")
    exit(1)

while True:
    sleep(100)
```

I run it like `echo "Y" | start-stop-daemon --start --exec /home/user/tests/startd.py` and it prints `exit!` and exits.

If it is the case that it requires multiple "Y"s you can try the `yes` program like 
`yes "Y" | start-stop-daemon --start --exec yourdaemon`.